# Multiprocessing in Flask code is not working

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have a Python definition 1 _ working when tried individually

I have a Python definition 2 in which definition 1 is called and being used - _ working when tried individually

Now I am planning to create a web application using Flask, Flask is running without any error but output data frames do not contain any data (Zero Rows)

How to run my Flask code successfully

```
import psycopg2_Working_V1

import multi_psycopg2

i = "store_3_item_26"


metrics_df_1,forecast_df_1 = multi_psycopg2.multi_post(i)
```

I am sanguine that if this works, then my Flask code will work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What has your code got to do with Flask?  Please include details how your posted code relates to your Flask app.